# Should I use an already master-linked chain or add a masterlink to a plain chain?

Tags: chain, frugal, master-link

Trying to find moderately-priced 9-speed chain is a pain, particularly with a master/missing link already installed. I can only find PC-971 master-linked chains from US market but shipping and handling ruins the deal. Then, I can find master links (like [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4483#4483)) but haven't yet found a chain. Also, the seller will sometimes only ship to a limited number of countries.

How would you buy if you wanted a master-linked 9-speed chain? Would you buy the chain and the link separate or together like in PC-971?

Comment: Ebay links are ephemeral, and often disappear in time. Is it possible to find another example link?

Comment: @Neil Fein: there is a serious danger that the question becomes too localized that way but luckily Benson provided some good ideas. I tried to attack the question from different slant: buy both, separate markets links are perhaps for emergence situations while master-linked chain for durability, not to allow customers to mess up with chains.

Comment: the cheaper substitute for the *SRAM PC-971* is *SRAM PC-951*, a bit heavier, discussion about lighter chains [1]. SRAM masterlinks are *golden* and can fairly easily be found from ebay.co.uk. The chain is one of the most important part [2] so do not underestimate your investment. [1] http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/are-lighter-chains-worth-the-cost [2] http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/are-all-9-speed-chains-compatible-with-all-9-speed-systems/2794#2794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been in a number of situations where I was really glad to have a master link that I could pull apart.  I'm a big fan of Sram's chains, and they're pretty reasonably priced here in the US.  In your position, I'd try hard to find a chain with a master link.

With that in mind, it's worth having (and even carrying with you) a spare master link.  If you do blow apart your chain, being able to put it back together is well worth the extra few milligrams in your bike pack.  Since they seem to come in 4-packs, it'd probably be fine to just find a chain and buy a pack of master links.

Comment: ...actually just realized master links can also be useful if your chain breaks, good idea to have some with you! +1

Comment: You probably also need a chain break tool to remove the damaged link.

Comment: Yeah, I carry a bike tool with a chain breaker in it. They can be pretty light and compact.

Comment: @Benson: I have an XLC chain breaker but its head got loose, which breaker are you using?

Comment: I'm using a cutter shorty: http://www.cutterbike.com/?cat=34&p=665

Comment: I have the original topeak alien tool, it's only aluminium but the chain tool has lasted for years

Comment: You can do it with your bare hands, too. Just gets you a little greasy.